# Array to XML same key issue

Tags: php, xml

I've tried array to xml. I'm newbie. I use that array2xml class. (On http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-xml-to-array-in-php-xml2array/)

My array:

```
$array = array();
$array['main']['head']['id'] = 1;
$array['main']['head']['type'] = 0;
$array['main']['head']['customerid'] = 10001;
$array['main']['address']['city'] = "BB";
$array['main']['address']['country'] = "AA";
$array['main']['orderlines']['line'][0]['prdcode'] = "1A2BC";
$array['main']['orderlines']['line'][0]['qty'] = 5;
$array['main']['orderlines']['line'][1]['prdcode'] = "2C2BC";
$array['main']['orderlines']['line'][1]['qty'] = 3;

$array['main'][0]['attr'][0]['line']['size'] = "100x200";
$array['main'][0]['attr'][0]['line']['color'] = "orange";
$array['main'][0]['attr'][1]['line']['size'] = "50x50";
$array['main'][0]['attr'][1]['line']['color'] = "orange";
$array['main'][1]['attr'][0]['line']['size'] = "75x200";
$array['main'][1]['attr'][0]['line']['color'] = "blue";
$array['main'][1]['attr'][1]['line']['size'] = "10x50";
$array['main'][1]['attr'][1]['line']['color'] = "green";
```

You can see is here: http://codepad.org/GrUa5rpD

I want to result like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<main>
    <head>
        <id>1</id>
        <type>0</type>
        <customerid>0</customerid>
    </head>
    <address>
        <city>BB</city>
        <country>AA</country>
    </address>
    <orderlines>
        <line>
            <prdcode>1A2BC</prdcode>
            <qty>5</qty>
        </line>
        <line>
            <prdcode>2C2BC</prdcode>
            <qty>3</qty>
        </line>
    </orderlines>
    <attr>
        <line>
            <size>100x200</size>
            <color>orange</color>
        </line>
        <line>
            <size>50x50</size>
            <color>orange</color>
        </line>
    </attr>
    <attr>
        <line>
            <size>75x200</size>
            <color>blue</color>
        </line>
        <line>
            <size>10x50</size>
            <color>green</color>
        </line>
    </attr>
</main>
```

My issue is when I convert PHP array 2 XML I get an error for `<attr>` tag. The key is not be numeric.

PHP error:
**`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '[Array2XML] Illegal character in tag name. tag: 0 in node: main`**

How can I fix this issue?
Thank you for your helps!

Comment: `<main>` is your document's root node. There can be only **ONE** `<main>` in your xml document, but you're telling the function that it's a multi-node, with the `[main][0]`, `[main][1]`, etc... xml node names cannot start with a number, which means the function is trying to make `<main><0>`, `<main><1>`, which isn't permitted.

Comment: @MarcB No. XML's root node is `<main>` I want to only `<attr>` tag like to attr[0], attr[1]... attr[n]

Comment: Yes, exactly, and you have `$array['main'][0]`.

Comment: @MarcB How can I genereate multiple `<attr>`?

Comment: `$array['main]['attr'][0]`

Comment: @MarcB I'm sorry :( I building wrong array. I update array section in my question.

Comment: @MarcB  Multiple `<attr>`s and multiple `<line>`s to inside `<attr>`

Answer (score 3):

This is the array structure you will need to create that xml:

```
$main['head']['id'] = 1;
$main['head']['type'] = 0;
$main['head']['customerid'] = 10001;
$main['address']['city'] = 0;
$main['address']['country'] = 10001;
$main['orderlines']['line'][0]['prdcode'] = "1A2BC";
$main['orderlines']['line'][0]['qty'] = 5;
$main['orderlines']['line'][1]['prdcode'] = "2C2BC";
$main['orderlines']['line'][1]['qty'] = 3;
$main['attr'][0]['line'][0]['size'] = "100x200";
$main['attr'][0]['line'][0]['color'] = "orange";
$main['attr'][0]['line'][1]['size'] = "50x50";
$main['attr'][0]['line'][1]['color'] = "orange";
$main['attr'][1]['line'][0]['size'] = "75x200";
$main['attr'][1]['line'][0]['color'] = "blue";
$main['attr'][1]['line'][1]['size'] = "10x50";
$main['attr'][1]['line'][1]['color'] = "green";

$xml = Array2XML::createXML('main', $main);
```

or formated a different way:

```
$main = array(
    'head'=> array(
        'id' => 1,
        'type' => 0,
        'customerid' => 10001
    ),
    'address'=> array(
        'city' => "BB",
        'country' => "AA"
    ),
    'orderlines'=> array(
        'line' => array(
            array (
                'prdcode' => "1A2BC",
                'qty' => 5
            ), array (
                'prdcode' => "2C2BC",
                'qty' => 3
            )
        )
    ),
    'attr'=> array(
        array('line' => array(
                array(
                    'size' => "100x200",
                    'color' => "orange"
                ),
                array(
                    'size' => "50x50",
                    'color' => "orange"
                )
            )
        ),
        array('line' => array(
                array(
                    'size' => "75x200",
                    'color' => "blue"
                ),
                array(
                    'size' => "10x50",
                    'color' => "green"
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
$xml = Array2XML::createXML('main', $main);
```